# Как отключить автоматическое обновление расширений оболочки Gnome-shell

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

У расширения "Vertical Workspaces" есть две версии - старая и новая... Всё бы ничего, только в той, которая устанавливается по умолчанию, есть конфликты с Dtd, и её каждый раз приходится перезапускать вручную. Нормальная же версия при установке работает ровно до тех пор, пока не перезагрузится сеанс. Как отключить автоматические обновления расширений для оболочки Gnome-shell?